# Which is better between prepared statement with 'LIKE '%' or generate query on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm implementing a typical list Rest endpoint `/items` with some optional filtering URI query parameters like `?attr=val&attr2=val` etc..

The Rest server is backed with Go/MySQL

About query performances, i wonder if it is better to create a prepared statement which make uses of LIKE statements :

```
SELECT cols from items WHERE attr LIKE ? and attr2 LIKE ?;
```

and simply set values to `'%'` to attributes not filled by the user

or generate the query on the fly based on given attrs ?

Exemple with no attrs:

```
SELECT cols from items;
```

Exemple with one attr:

```
SELECT cols from items where attr LIKE 'val';
```

More generally i wonder if using `LIKE '%'` has a performance cost (considering indexes are configured properly on theses cols). And if theses performances costs are worth in a prepared statement compared to the cost of generate the query on the fly (parsing etc.).

Note: The number of distinct filtering attrs beeing pretty significant    it is not conceivable to generate specific prepared statement for every possible attrs combination.

Comment: *if using `LIKE '%'` has a performance cost* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a96fefa177a263bb196c9ce6ea30114 - `WHERE col LIKE '%'` provides unneeded overhead.

Comment: I In your first example, you are using LIKE, in your second example you are using = when comparing to the attribute. Which one do you really need? If to use LIKE or = operator doesn't depend if you use a prepared statement or not. LIKE is very slow and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Create SP which accepts all filter values entered by the user (NULLs for non-specified values), build SQL query dynamically depends on the provided non-NULL values and execute it. If the amount of parameters is low enough then you may not build the query text dynamically but select it from predefined queries texts list.

Comment: @JonasMetzier "=" was just a typo. I edited my question and replace with 'LIKE'. Thanks

Comment: @Akina I didn't think to use stored procedure but it sounds like a good idea. Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use `LIKE` if an `attr` is set in the filter (do you ever do a search like `attr LIKE '%val%'`? Or if `attr` is present will the test then actually be `attr = 'val'`? `attr LIKE 'val'` is from the outcome mostly equivalent to `attr='val'` if no `%` are involved.

Comment: @t.niese absolutely not, '=' is okay. But i'm looking for a way to make theses attributes optional in a prepared statement. But i'm aware of the cost of LIKE statement compared to '='.

Comment: @sgt-hartman Yes, but you also should make clear what you actually want to achieve. The `LIKE` is how **you** try to solve it, but that might not be the way how to target the problem correctly. So you should be clear about what you actually want to test.

Comment: @t.niese You are right. Here my first intend was to use LIKE as a workaround and not the  pure expression of the query but its wrong. I think i will make a prepared statement for the case without any filter (most common use case) and create a stored procedure to generate query for cases with filters as suggested by Akina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parts involved when you are doing a query.

1. Parsing the query.
2. Optimizing the query based on the query structure and the used parameter values.
3. Doing the query using the optimized query.

The query optimizer technically could optimize `LIKE '%'` away to something not using `LIKE`, but it seems as if MySQL doesn't do that (but I'm not 100% sure about that).

For booleans, the query optimizer however does such optimizations.

If you do:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (attr='val' OR TRUE) AND (attr2='val' OR FALSE);
```

The resulting query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE attr2='val';
```

Because `(attr='val' OR TRUE)` will always be `TRUE`, and `OR FALSE` doesn't do anything.

So you could always have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (attr=@attr OR !@useAttr) AND (attr2=@attr2 OR !@useAttr2);
```

And enable/disable the usage of the corresponding filter using a boolean.

Or something like this if the value is `null` if it is not set:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (attr=? OR ISNULL(?)) AND (attr2=? OR ISNULL(?));
```

And call the query like that `stmnt.execute(attr, attr, attr2, attr2)`.

Comment: Your solution completely fulfill in a very elegant way my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you spend a little effort building the query based on the data provided.  That is, construct the `WHERE` clause with only the items that the user wants to search on.

This may or may not actually speed things up, but it does help you think about your UI and could lead to better UI designs.

When a column could be, say, 0 or NULL and they mean the same thing, performance suffers by using `OR`.  Instead, rethink the schema -- pick either 0 or NULL, not both, as an indicator of whatever.

If you tend to have `LIKE '%xyz%'`, consider whether a `FULLTEXT` index would be more appropriate (and a lot faster).

(Meanwhile, @t.niese discusses optimization nicely.)